# Is this workout schedule good for cutting fat and maintaining muscle mass?

Tags: weight-loss, strength, muscle-mass

Day 1: Upper Body + Cardio

Upper Body Strength:

Push-Ups: 3 sets of 12 reps
Dumbbell Rows: 3 sets of 12 reps per arm
Dumbbell Bench Press: 3 sets of 12 reps
Bicep Curls: 3 sets of 12 reps
Tricep Dips: 3 sets of 12 reps
Cardio (45 minutes)

Day 2: Lower Body + Cardio

Lower Body Strength:

Squats: 3 sets of 15 reps
Lunges: 3 sets of 12 reps per leg
Leg Press Machine: 3 sets of 12 reps
Calf Raises: 3 sets of 15 reps
Cardio (45 minutes)

Day 3: Core + Cardio

Core Strength:

Plank: 3 sets, hold for 1 minute each
Russian Twists: 3 sets of 20 reps
Bicycle Crunches: 3 sets of 20 reps
Cardio (45 minutes)

Day 4: Upper Body + Cardio

Upper Body Strength:

Pull-Ups or Lat Pulldowns: 3 sets of 12 reps
Dumbbell Shoulder Press: 3 sets of 12 reps
Dumbbell Flyes: 3 sets of 12 reps
Hammer Curls: 3 sets of 12 reps
Skull Crushers: 3 sets of 12 reps
Cardio (45 minutes): Choose a cardio activity you enjoy and maintain a moderate to high intensity.

Day 5: Lower Body + Cardio

Lower Body Strength:

Deadlifts: 3 sets of 12 reps
Leg Curls: 3 sets of 12 reps
Bulgarian Split Squats: 3 sets of 12 reps per leg
Seated Calf Raises: 3 sets of 15 reps
Cardio (45 minutes)

Day 6: Core + Cardio

Core Strength:

Hanging Leg Raises: 3 sets of 12 reps
Plank Twists: 3 sets of 20 reps (10 per side)
Reverse Crunches: 3 sets of 15 reps
Cardio (45 minutes)

Day 7: Rest or Light Activity

---

Is this workout schedule efficient for losing fat and maintaining muscle? My main goal is to lose fat but still maintain my muscle.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are doing for cardio? Training stress is cumulative, and unless you are doing it for something specific, you may not need it. Muscle mass consumes more calories to build and maintain than fat does, so the muscle building alone will reduce fat (But increase weight, as muscle tissue weighs more than the equivalent volume of fat tissue).

Comment: @JohnP im doing the treadmill for cardio. im doing the cardio to lose the fat.